# Algorithm for sorting array of numbers into sets

Tags: javascript, sorting, splice

I have a n array of n objects like so:

```
[{'item1': 144},
 {'item2': 0},
 {'item3': 366},
 {'item4': 15},
 {'item6': 366},
 {'item7': 19},
 {'item8': 211},
 {'item9': 121}]
```

The item values are 0-n.

I need to represent these items with varying size depending on their values.

To do this, my initial thoughts were to splice the array into four minor arrays: XL, L, M, S.

I'm not sure how to go about sorting the array into these 4 sets.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: please specify the range of XL, L, M, S.

Comment: I guess L, M, S would be easier. Find the largest value, save, and push to L and remove it, find the lowest value, save, and push to S and remove it, compare last L with last S, then find medium value and push to M and remove it.

Comment: @NinaScholz the rage is n

Comment: please add a wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz  
Something along these lines:
XL: [{'item6': 366}, {'item3': 366}]
L: [{'item8': 211}, {'item1': 144}]
M: [{'item9': 121}]
S: [{'item7': 19}, {'item2': 0}, {'item4': 15}]

Answer (score 0):

A solution, using the third party library [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

```js
var arr = [
   {'item1': 144},
   {'item2': 0},
   {'item3': 366},
   {'item4': 15},
   {'item5': 366},
   {'item6': 19},
   {'item7': 211},
   {'item8': 121}];

//max value n
var n = 400;

var result = _.groupBy(arr, function(item, i){ 
    var val = item["item" + (i + 1)];

    //group together values that are in the same quarter of the max value n
    if (val < n / 4) {
        return "S";
    } else if (val < n / 2) {
        return "M";
    } else if (val < 0.75 * n) {
        return "L";
    } else {
        return "XL";
    }
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal with ranges for XL, L, M, S and an object for the grouped result.

```js
var data = [{ 'item1': 144 }, { 'item2': 0 }, { 'item3': 366 }, { 'item4': 15 }, { 'item6': 366 }, { 'item7': 19 }, { 'item8': 211 }, { 'item9': 121 }],
    range = { XL: 400, L: 300, M: 200, S: 100 },
    keys = Object.keys(range).sort(function (a, b) { return range[a] - range[b]; }),
    groups = {};

keys.forEach(function (k) { groups[k] = []; });

data.forEach(function (a) {
    keys.some(function (k) {
        var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
        if (a[key] < range[k]) {
            groups[k].push(a);
            return true;
        }
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(groups, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```